# Remove array delimiters

Tags: javascript

Is it possible remove delimiters when you array.toString? (javascript)

```
var myArray = [ 'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ];
var result = myArray .toString();
```

result shoud be "zeroonetwothreefourfive"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use `join` instead of `toString` -

```
var myArray = [ 'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ];
var result = myArray.join('');
```

`join` will join all the elements of the array into a string using the argument passed to the `join` function as a delimiter. So calling `join` and passing in an empty string should do exactly what you require.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/jAEVY/

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `Array.join()` to achieve this:

```
var arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
    str1 = arr.join(""), // "foobarbaz"
    str2 = arr.join(":"); // "foo:bar:baz"
```

Whatever you specify in the `join` method will be used as the delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array.join("separator")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead.

```
["a", "b", "c"].join("");  // "abc"
["a", "b", "c"].join(" "); // "a b c"
["a", "b", "c"].join(","); // "a,b,c"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can you the `replace`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)</sup>* method:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4],
    arrStr = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the separator is `,` to remove the separetor use the function `.replace(/,/g,'')`

But if there is comma `,` in the data you might want to consider something like

```
var str = '';
for(var x=0; x<array.length; x++){
  str += array[x];
}
```